# Why didn't this flush win the game?

Tags: pokerstars

The other player wins with a straight, but I had a flush. Why do I lose?

[image]

Comment: In Omaha, you're forced to play 2 cards from your hand. Any combination of course, but 2 cards minimum. So your K, A is just high card.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Seems like, you did not have a flush.

According to the [Omaha Hi/Lo Poker rules](http://www.pokerstars.com/poker/games/omaha/high-low/) from Pokerstars:

> All players use exactly two cards from their four hole cards in conjunction with exactly three cards from the board to make the best five-card poker hand possible.

Since you only had 1 diamonds card (King) in your hole cards (your hand), you could not make a flush.

Answer (score 9):

The [rules for Omaha High Low](http://www.pokersyte.com/omaha_hilo.htm) state that you have to use two cards from your hole and three from the board to make a hand.

Your flush only included one card from your hole.